# How to calculate frequency received data from time column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with received time like the below:

[image]

As you see, the frequency of received data in some rows is different and they are 1000ms, 1001ms, 998ms.

How can I calculate the average frequency of received time in ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerQuery add an Index column to your data so that you can address singe rows. Then with DAX add a calulated column to the table:

```
Milliseconds = 
VAR NextIndex = 'Table'[Index] + 1
VAR MaxIndex = MAX(Table[Index])
VAR Difference =
    IF( 
        'Table'[Index] = MaxIndex,
        BLANK(),        
        'Table'[date_time] -
            CALCULATE(
                VALUES('Table'[date_time]),
                Filter(
                    ALL('Table'), 
                    'Table'[Index] = NextIndex
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
     CONVERT(ABS(Difference * 3600 * 24 * 1000), INTEGER)
```

Now you are looking for **AVERAGE( Milliseconds )**.

*Note: Things would have been easier if you provided copyable data instead of a screenshot.*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Power Query to

- add a column that is the original date_time column offset by 1
- Then add another column showing the difference between current row and previous row

*This method, at least in M Code, is faster than using an Index column to refer to previous row*

Then you can do your mathematical analyses.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("dc27DcAgDAXAVRA1An9iO2EVxP5rgEQZXn3FjZGjsTUh4cRdqctTwy3P8heD4lv8KgHl3RJX+dCjBIXRo3JkLg==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [date_time = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date_time", type datetime}}),

//add column containing previous rows data
//usually faster than using and INDEX column
    prevList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type"[date_time]),
    tbl1 = Table.FromColumns(
        {#"Changed Type"[date_time],prevList},
        {"date_time","Prev Row"}
        
    ),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(tbl1, "Difference", each /*if [Prev Row] = null then 0 
        else*/ Duration.TotalSeconds([date_time] - [Prev Row])),

    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{
        {"date_time", type datetime}, {"Prev Row", type datetime}, {"Difference", type number}})

in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]